# How can to get the JSON out of webpage?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, python-requests

So I'm trying to parse data out of this [webpage](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/components/certificate_transparency/data/log_list.json)

But I don't need the whole dataset, I just need:

- The operator name (Google, CloudFlare, etc.)
- The description (Google 'Argon2022' log, Google 'Argon2023' log, etc.)
- The logIDs (`KXm+8J45OSHwVnOfY6V35b5XfZxgCvj5TV0mXCVdx4Q=`)

I tried to write some code but I'm just a beginner at webscraping, so was wondering if anyone could help. Here is my attempted code, I tried using lxml and requests library.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page = requests.get('https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/components/certificate_transparency/data/log_list.json')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of operators:
operators = tree.xpath('//span[@class="operators"]/text()')

print('Operators: ',operators)
```

My hope is to have an end result that looks like the JSON on the website minus all the unneeded info so operators:

```
[
  { "name": "Google",
    "logs": [
      { description: "Google Argon2022 log",
        log_id: "KXm+8J45OSHwVnOfY6V35b5XfZxgCvj5TV0mXCVdx4Q=" }, 
      { description: "GoogleArgon2023 log",
        log_id: "6D7Q2j71BjUy51covIlryQPTy9ERa+zraeF3fW0GvW4=" }
  }
  ....
  { "name": "CloudFlare",
    "logs": [ ... ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you want to access the raw file, and not the UI. Just like Kache mentioned, you can get the JSON using:

```
resp = requests.get('https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/components/certificate_transparency/data/log_list.json?format=TEXT')
obj = json.loads(base64.decodebytes(resp.text.encode()))
```

Then, you can use the following script to extract only the data you want:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

def extract_log(log):
    keys = [ 'description', 'log_id' ]
    return { key: log[key] for key in keys }

def extract_logs(logs):
    return [ extract_log(log) for log in logs ]

def extract_operator(operator):
    return {
        'name': operator['name'],
        'logs': extract_logs(operator['logs'])
    }

def extract_certificates(obj):
    return [ extract_operator(operator) for operator in obj['operators'] ]

def scrape_certificates(url):
    resp = requests.get(url)
    obj = json.loads(base64.decodebytes(resp.text.encode()))
    return extract_certificates(obj)

def main():
    out = scrape_certificates('https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/components/certificate_transparency/data/log_list.json?format=TEXT')
    print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for your help, I've been trying to build on what you gave me and added this to your print statement ```json.loads(json.dumps(out, indent=4))``` which returns a list instead of a str, but I think it would be more helpful for a dict to be returned so that I can easily parse what I need. The end goal is for me to compare the log_Id in this dictionary to a file I have and then return the name like Google and the description like Google Argon2022. And honestly it may be easier to return the information if the name and log information were on the same level.

Comment: Never mind I figured it out I just had to do use multiple loops

Comment: Hey @Daniel I actually had to come back to this, because apparently my list isn't exhaustive and I've been racking my brain on trying to create a function of a dictionary that contains similar values to use for this function. These are the values I want to use for now ```log_id = some_log_Id
log_description = 'Digicert named log'
operator_name = 'Digicert'``` but I keep hitting errors. I'll keep trying to work at it.

Comment: @Alex, not sure I understand how is this different from the current proposed solution? You have the operator name (name) and a list of all the logs, each containing the ID and the description. You mean you wanna flatten that list out? so that you have long array of tuples `[(name, id, desc), (name, id, desc), ...]`?

Comment: Thanks Daniel I figured it out. Well with the help of another but we basically went through the obj and an an if statement to look for Digicert and added the information if it wasn’t there else we kept the original values.

Comment: Daniel, hope all is well, so I deployed the solution above in our production environment and so as a result I'm getting a lot more data so it works for a good bit of time but then outputs this error ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 2: invalid start byte```. Do you think it's because I'm hitting the URL so much or is it something else ?

Comment: here is a better stack
```obj = json.loads(base64.decodebytes(resp.text.encode()))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 349, in loads
    s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 2: invalid start byte```

Comment: Hey Daniel I figured it out I had to move it outside the loop and it didn’t break. I think I was being throttled.

Answer (score 1):

There is a link at the bottom right that lets you download the file directly:         https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/components/certificate_transparency/data/log_list.json?format=JSON

Which lets you avoid HTML parsing altogether.

Here's Python code to extract it as a `dict`:

```py
resp = requests.get('https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/components/certificate_transparency/data/log_list.json?format=TEXT')
js = json.loads(base64.decodebytes(resp.text.encode()))
```

What remains of your question involves JSON and `dict` traversal and basic coding, which you should be able to find answers in other questions.

Comment: ahh I wonder if I could just download it in my code, cause the reason I'm trying to do this is to make sure the file stays current and I don't have to update the code every time a new log comes out. Do you know how I could just download the file within my code?

Comment: yeah I think I can get the JSON parsing and traversal down, I just need to get the whole page available for me to parse :D

Comment: added python code example

Comment: thanks Kache that was really helpful! I will work on parsing what I need, but that was what I was struggling with.